# Extjs Date field Rowediting Losing It's Value

Tags: extjs, datefield, roweditor

I have a `grid` with `RowEditing` enabled with some `dateFields` and when I try to edit, date field value gets blanked. Forcing the user to select the date again. Though upon cancel edit, old values are displayed.
attached screenshot [dateFieldGetBlanked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LErqo.png)

```
{
    text: 'Quote Date',
    dataIndex: 'quote_date',
    menuDisabled: true,
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    format:'M d, Y',
    flex: 1,
    editor: {
        xtype : 'datefield', 
        allowBlank : false
    }
}
```

This behavior is not replicable in `cellediting`, it works fine there.

Any idea whats causing this problem in `rowediting`, any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**type: 'date'** inside modal fields array should fix it.

Here is behaviour replicated.
Fiddle with `type:date` : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nj0
Fiddle with datefield as string: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nj1